# Dividing a triangle into four congruent triangles. Proof how this works?

Tags: proof-writing, euclidean-geometry

So for any triangle, you can divide it into four congruent triangles by connecting the midpoints of each side. But I want to see how this works.

[image]

How does SR can be proved to be equal to AQ? SQ equal to RC? RQ equal to AS?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Midsegment Theorem?  (Also called the Medial Line Theorem.)  It states that a segment joining the midpoints of two sides of a triangle is parallel to, and half the length of, the third side.  If you have that available, the proof is fairly trivial.

Comment: With $R$ and $S$ specified as midpoints, you know that $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle SBR$ via Side-Angle-Side Similarity: corresponding angles (at $B$) are congruent; corresponding sides are proportional (here with ratio $2:1$). Consequently, $|AC|:|SR| = 2:1$, which implies $|AQ| = |SR| = |QC|$.

Comment: @Blue shouldn't we use AAA similarity? Doesn't SAS only used to indicate two triangles are exactly the same?

Comment: @mweiss I looked it up thank you.

Comment: @user3000482: There's Side-Angle-Side **Congruence** and there's Side-Angle-Side **Similarity**. Two different results.

Answer (score 1):

$S$ is the midpoint of $AB$, so $|AS| = |SB| = \frac{|AB|}{2}$. Similarly for $R$, $|BR| = |RC| = \frac{|BC|}{2}$. Also, $\angle ABC = \angle SBR$, so by SSA similarity $\triangle BSR \sim \triangle ABC$. The common ratio is $1:2$, so $|SR| = \frac{|AC|}{2} = |AQ| = |QC|$. The same goes for $\triangle CQR$ and $\triangle ASQ$.