# Refinement of triangles

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods

I have given the triangulation in black:

[image]

The task is to refine the two triangles on the top (left) in 4 congruent triangles each. I have done this in red colour.

In addition to that, there should not be any hanging nodes. I tried this using the violet colour. Is this correct, or is there any fault?

Thanks in advance for checking my draft.

Corrected version:

[image]

Comment: Check the 2 triangles in the top left square block. You forgot making 2 lines.

Comment: May help:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885393/dividing-a-triangle-into-four-congruent-triangles-proof-how-this-works

Answer (score -1):

This is it maybe if I figured out your question correctly.

[image]

Comment: Oh yes, I just forgot to add the two lines to the picture. I added a corrected version. Does it hold true now?